# Formulario que no envia correos

Tags: html5, formularios

Tengo este código extraido de una plantilla de una web y no se que debo cambiar para que me envie las respuestas a mi correo.

```
    <form>
      <div class="row gtr-50">
        <div class="col-6 col-12-mobilep">
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-12-mobilep">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="submit" class="button alt" value="Send Message" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Saludos por si solo ese formulario HTML no enviara a tu correo ningun dato, dado que para esto necesitas usar una librería como PHPMailer por ende PHP que será quien reciba tus campos del formulario y posteriormente enviarlos a donde desees..te sugiero revisar: http://reusableforms.com/d/b/phpmailer-contact-form

Comment: se poco de html y eso lo veo complicado para mi, pero gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 4):

Puedes reemplazar `<form>` por `<form action="mailto:tu@tuemail.com">`> y vas a recibir el contenido. No funciona con todos los browsers, puede disparar un warning y tiene el inconveniente de exponer la dirección email a todos los programas que hacen email harvesting y vas a recibir mucho spam, pero es la solución mas simple. La otra es de apuntar a un script en un servidor que manda el email. O tambien puedes usar un servicio como https://formspree.io/. (Disclaimer: no formo parte de formspree.io)

Comment: lo he probado pero no hace nada, lo he puesto asi
<form action="mailto:miemail@gmail.com">
y asi:
<form action="mailto:miemail@gmail.com" method="POST">
y ninguno hace nada

Comment: @Basicmix lo que hace "mailto" no envia tu correo por ti, eso solo abre tu programa gestor de correos como Outlook, thunderbir, etc...como te dije debes hacer tu propio script php para enviar dicho formulario hacia tu correo en el enlace que te deje explica ello